# Using while on a method returning multiple values

Tags: java

Here I'm trying to use `while` on a method using also `while` in order to return multiple values from a SQL request. Where am I wrong here? Is there another way than using `boolean` to do this?

Database table

| 1st Column |
| --- |
| 1000 |
| 900 |
| 800 |

Program printing the values from the table

```
public class someClass {
    
    public static int value;

    public static boolean getValues() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet valuesResult = requestQuery(valuesQuery);
        while (valuesResult .next()) {
            value=  sessionUsersResult.getInt(1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database.connect();
        while (getValues()) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Actual result in the console

```
1000
1000
1000 ...
[infinite loop]
```

Expected result

```
1000
900
800
```

Comment: `while(getValues())` will call the `getValues()` method on each iteration, result in a fresh new executed query, from which you will read (only) the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `getValues` it always do the new query. Also you are spinning it in loop in main, where it always calls the function that returns firts query.

You have several options.

You can do the logic you want during iteration:

```
public class someClass {
    
    public static int value;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database.connect();
        ResultSet valuesResult = requestQuery(valuesQuery);
        while (valuesResult .next()) {
            value =  sessionUsersResult.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(value)
        }
    }
}
```

You can put everything to List or Array and return it after you iterate through it and then manipulate it

```
public static List<Integer> getValues() throws SQLException {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ResultSet valuesResult = requestQuery(valuesQuery);
    while (valuesResult .next()) {
        list.add(sessionUsersResult.getInt(1));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Or you can put there parameter that do something with these values:

```
public static void forEachValue(Consumer<Integer> consumer) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet valuesResult = requestQuery(valuesQuery);
    while (valuesResult .next()) {
        consumer.accept(sessionUsersResult.getInt(1));
    }
}
```

You can use this with a Lambda:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Database.connect();
    forEachValue(value -> System.out.println(value));        
}
```